# How to turn a optional of an string array into a optional of a string?

Tags: java, java-stream, optional-chaining

I struggle with finding an elegant way to convert a variable of type `Optional<String[]>` to `Optional<String>` and joining all elements of the given array.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

```java
Optional<String[]> given = Optional.ofNullable(new String[]{"a", "b"});

Optional<String> joinedString = ....;

Assertions.assertThat(joinedString.get()).isEqualTo("ab");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like a simple `map` operation with `String.join()`.

```
Optional<String[]> given = Optional.ofNullable(new String[]{"a", "b"});
var joinedString = given.map(s -> String.join("", s));
System.out.println(joinedString.get()); // prints "ab"
```